# Cake pattern nested traits

Tags: scala, cake-pattern

Why everyone is using this form of definition:

```
trait UserServiceComponent {
  def userService: UserService
  trait UserService {
    def findAll: List[User]
    def save(user: User)
  }
}
```

Instead of that:

```
trait UserService {
  def findAll: List[User]
  def save(user: User)
}

trait UserServiceComponent {
  def userService: UserService
}
```

Second approach seems more universal because UserService trait is not bound to specific component instance.

Anything I'm missing?

Edit:
By "more universal" I mean that you can do something like this (mix two cakes with different impl. into one):

```
object Program extends App with UserServiceComponent with ProductServiceComponent  {
    object Cake1 extends UserServiceComponentImpl with DatabaseComponent1Impl {
    }
    object Cake2 extends ProductServiceComponentImpl with DatabaseComponent2Impl {
    }

    def userService = Cake1.userService
    def productService = Cake2.productService
}

// def
trait DatabaseComponent{
}

trait UserService {
}

trait UserServiceComponent {
  def userService: UserService
}

trait ProductService {
}

trait ProductServiceComponent {
  def productService: ProductService
}

// impl
trait DatabaseComponent1Impl extends DatabaseComponent {
}

trait DatabaseComponent2Impl extends DatabaseComponent {
}

trait UserServiceComponentImpl extends UserServiceComponent {
    self:DatabaseComponent =>

    def userService = new UserService {}
}

trait ProductServiceComponentImpl extends ProductServiceComponent {
    self:DatabaseComponent =>

    def productService = new ProductService {}
}
```

If you define UserService as nested trait then you'll get an exception: 
type mismatch; found: Program.Cake1.UserService, required: Program.UserService

Answer (score 3):

In your second construction, the population of the global namespace is doubled for no good reason. With the classic Cake construction a component is self-contained and it injects exactly one name into the global namespace.

In either event, the characteristic of the component (here `trait UserService`) is equally available whether structured as classic Cake or your alternative. That is, your alternative is by no means "more universal."

Comment: Randall, I explained a bit more, though Vladimir was quicker then me :) So, there is no other reasons to nest but to prevent namespace pollution, right?

Answer (score 1):

Randall Schulz' answer is absolutely correct. I'd only add that sometimes the second form (with top-level `UserService`) is inevitable. For example, when you have to pass components from "outer" cake to "inner" cake:

```
trait ExampleComponent {
    def example: Example
}

trait Example {
    def doSomething()
}

trait DefaultExampleComponent {
    override val example = new Example {
        // ...
    }
}

trait SomeOtherComponent { self: ExampleComponent =>
    object InnerCake extends ExampleComponent {
        override def example = self.example
    }
}

object TopLevelCake extends DefaultExampleComponent with SomeOtherComponent
```

If `Example` was an inner trait of `ExampleComponent`, then assignment

```
override def example = self.example
```

wouldn't be possible, because `self.example` has type `SomeOtherComponent.this.type#Example` but `InnerCake.example` should be of type `this.type#Example`.